# [C++ ]'File' : is not a class or namespace name

Tags: visual-c++

```
INCLUDE and USINGS
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Xml;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
```

I trying to make a filemover project. I take a referance a video on Youtube. This youtuber can work this codes but I can't. I get this error: 'File' : is not a class or namespace name.`enter code here`

```
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
            openFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
            textBox1->Text = openFileDialog1->FileName;
         }
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
                openFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
                textBox2->Text = openFileDialog1->FileName;
         }
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         File::Move(textBox1->Text,textBox2->Text);
         MessageBox::Show("Succes");
     }
};
```

ERRORS

> (138): error C2653: 'File' : is not a class or namespace name
>   (138): error C3728: 'event System::EventHandler ^System::Windows::Forms::Control::Move': event does not have a raise method
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: The MSDN article for .NET classes like File shows the namespace name and assembly name at the top of the article.  So you'll know to add `using namespace System::IO;` or spell out the full name, `System::IO::File::Move(...);`

Comment: It is work! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

File is located in System::IO, so you should be using this assembly too.